# Figure out in setup.py what repository this package is being installed from?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

Say I have a python package `blah`

I can install it in two ways:

`pip install git+https://github.com/blah/blah.git@blah` (using github repo)

and

`pip install blah` (using pypi repo)

Is there a way to figure out which of the way the user is installing the package in `setup.py` ?

So that I can essentially do something like:

```
if INSTALLING_FROM_PYPI:
   # some logic
if INSTALLING_FROM_SOMEWHERE_ELSE:
   # some other logic
```

Comment: Are there any differences between the modules?

Comment: No, the package on pypi and the one on github are 100% the same, including the setup.py script. I could "solve" this by having a different setup.py on github and a different one on pypi, but that would be rather tedious to maintain.

Comment: The only method I can see would be to create a blank object like `FROM-GIT` inside the git version, then do a try-except around importing that from the code.

Comment: @JammyDodger "*create a blank object like FROM-GIT*" No need — just test for `.git` directory.

Comment: But how do I get the path to that object ? As in, do I have a guarantee that `setup.py` is executed in a specific place so I can get a relative path to the FROM-GIT file ?

Comment: Otherwise this idea seems good, I can just exclude FROM-GIT from the manifest and that would be a good enough solution

Answer (score 0):

Just include a file in your Git repository:

```
$ touch .git-flag
```

Explicitly exclude it from your distribution in your `MANIFEST.in` file:

```
exclude .git-flag
```

Then in `setup.py`, check for the existence of that file relative to your `setup.py` file:

```py
import os

this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
path_to_flag = os.path.join(this_dir, ".git-flag")
installed_from_git = os.path.exists(path_to_flag)
```